# Как сделать так, чтобы второе условие switch выполнилось только в конкретном случае?

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы второе условие switch выполнилось только в том случае, если выполнилось первое? Также всегда должно выполняться третье условие. [Ссылка на пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ddff6c6977a5f6edd17389e916a5d8c182bddbcf).

```
<?php

   $array = array("first", "second", "third");

  foreach ($array as $val) {
    switch($val) {
        case "first":
            break;
        case "second":
            break;
        case "third":
            break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: зачем тут switch?

Comment: Суть задачи от этого не меняется! Я упростил код из исходника.

Comment: Скажем иначе, почему не if?

Comment: Убрать `break;`

Comment: Задача не имеет смысла. Что значит _второе условие switch выполнилось только в том случае, если выполнилось первое_? Какое условие то? Вы перебираете массив и проверяете `$val`, и... В один момент времени `$val` может иметь только одно значение.